# Data validation in sencha

Tags: validation, sencha-touch-2, dataview

I am creating a model for a form which needs some validations.

The model looks like this:

```
//Defining a data structure for the Work Item List
Ext.define('InfoImage.model.configure.configModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    config : {
        //Defining the fields required in the Work Item List
        fields : [ 'servname', 'port', 'protocol', 'username', 'password',
                'domain', 'appconfig', 'apptitle', 
                'appconfig' ],

        validations : [ 
        {
            type : 'presence',
            name : 'servname'
        }, 
        {
            type : 'presence',
            name : 'port'
        //  matcher : /[0-9]{4}[A-Z]+/
        }, 
        {
            type : 'presence',
            name : 'username'
        },
        {
            type : 'presence',
            name : 'password'
        }],
        proxy : {
            type : 'localstorage',
            id : 'configId'
        }
    }
});
```

I tried calling the validation by

```
Ext.getCmp('form').validate();
```

but it says that it has no method called validation.

Does sencha provide a method for validation? If yes, how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha does indeed provide a method for validating **models**. Have a read through the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/models-section-3

I guess you can use [form.getValues()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getValues) to populate a new model, and then use the validate() method on the model to validate the data.